# How to chnage this value theHour[0].times into time format (HH:mm) using moment.js

Tags: c#, jquery, json, chart.js, momentjs

I would like to have the timescale line chart but the labels didnt show in time format. How can i change the labels into time format. as for now, the labels value in int value which the value are [{3,5,6}]

```
 var myChartLine = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: theHour[0].times,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Overall',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    fill: false,
                    data: theHour[0].overall,
                    datalabels: {
                        labels: {
```

what im trying to do is , i try to change the labels :

```
moment(theHour[0].times.toString(), "HH:mm")
```

but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to date and format it to "HH:mm"

```js
var theHour = [3,15,16];
console.log(moment(new Date(0, 0, 0, theHour[0], 0, 0, 0)).format("HH:mm"));
console.log(moment(new Date(0, 0, 0, theHour[1], 0, 0, 0)).format("HH:mm"));
console.log(moment(new Date(0, 0, 0, theHour[2], 0, 0, 0)).format("hh:mm A"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```